# Run loaded script again (after modification) in Browser's Inspect Tools?

Tags: web-inspector, inspect

For example, on page I have a button, which causes to fire XYZ function (which is already loaded inside namespace in external JS).

[image]

However, I wanted there to change only one function in that script only (not page), and reload that script again, so, that the BUTTON will fire the modified function..

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem.
You can use the console to redefine the function.

Just click F12, go to Console, 
then type in your edited function and click enter.

Then click the button and the modified function will be executed.

**Note** When editing the function from the console, make sure that you are in the right context:
[image]

If you type the function name and get a function this means you can edit it. If you get `undefined`, this means you are not in the right context and should change the scope in which the function is defined in.
You can change scope in Chrome's console if needed by using this dropdown (for example when the code is run from an iframe):
[image]